# TensorFlow fit method takes long time to start the training

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I'm training to fit a pretty simple model:

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_3 (InputLayer)        [(None, 24, 25)]          0         
                                                                 
 gru (GRU)                   (None, 24, 64)            17472     
                                                                 
 flatten_2 (Flatten)         (None, 1536)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_6 (Dense)             (None, 128)               196736    
                                                                 
 dense_7 (Dense)             (None, 64)                8256      
                                                                 
 dense_8 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 65        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 222,529
Trainable params: 222,529
Non-trainable params: 0
```

And I found that it takes a lot of time for the model to ***start*** the training right after the `model.fit` method is executed — around 10 - 15 minutes of preparation before I see the progress bar starting. I noticed that if I reduce the number of samples in the training set, then it is much faster. However, I don't understand why as Tensorflow should load the dataset by batches (right?), it should start the training once it can.

Is there anything to do as it seems like TensorFlow is waiting to load the entire dataset or most of it before starting the training (otherwise, what is the problem, and how do I see such huge differences?)?

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, TensorFlow is loading the entire dataset (or a large subset of it) before starting the training. I fixed this using the `prefetch` method of `tf.data.Dataset`.